# How to make the mouse a priority for cpu processing(mouse freezes)?

Tags: cpu, mouse, freeze

I've come to ask if there is a way to make the mouse a priority for the cpu?
I couldn't find anything about it online but i did find out is that it's a pretty common problem that the mouse freezes under heavy cpu load. 
My cpu is not too strong and too many times when i play on my pc my cpu goes to very high load and what happens is my mouse freezes when it peaks...
So my guess is if the mouse got the priority it would prefer handling the mouse before anything else and the problem would stop...

Comment: Which operating system you have? which program was running when the mouse freezes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system process that handles your mouse *already* has the highest priority possible. The real problem here is that your CPU is so busy it cannot handle the hardware interrupts generated by your mouse.

You need to either reduce the load on your CPU, or get a faster computer.

Comment: I understand. Well i guess i'll just have to deal with it hehe, thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

open Taskmanager (CTRL + SHIFT + ESC),

In Windows 7:
Under tab 'processes' find the process called explorer.exe, right click, and set priority to 'high'.

In Windows 10, you'll find explorer.exe under the tab 'details' instead.

Comment: I guess it is not explorer.exe because if you kill explorer.exe process, you can still use your mouse.

Answer (score -1):

Get a program called BES it can slow down programs and make the mouse speed up - no more lagging. BES = Battle Encoder Shirase

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [how to recommend software in answers](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers), particularly the bits in **bold**; then edit your answer to follow the guidelines there. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Don't believe it - open the process explorer and run a search on "MOUSE" to find all the associated processes.  Right click and check "PRIORITY" -- probably running in normal (8) -- kick it up to high (13).

Comment: That is singularly dangerous advice. The processes which host mouse communication are the System processes, and they don't just host the mouse. You'd be setting up the computer to be unable to handle anything at all doing that.